# Create Custom InternetHeader in Outlook C#

Tags: c#, outlook

I Want to Create CustomInternetHeader in Outlook and Set this Value per mail.
and also display in Outlook Mail Option.
Can you help on this How to Create Custom Internet Header

Comment: What have you tryed so far ?

Comment: const string SchemaPR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D";        //mailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(SchemaPR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "Test_Data_123");

Comment: At the moment your question is of low quality and is unlikely to attract many helpful answers. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: We have a One Functionality while Outlook mail sync in Exchange Server. we set one properties in Mail for that we have created one ADD in and Set One property for specific mail so we can identify while we read in Exchange servies.
while sync process is started we read only those mails for further process(DB Entry) which we have set custom properties in Outlook.
I have read some blog in Internet and I found that for thet we need to create CustomInternet Header and read it in exchange services.
Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: My Question is How we set Mail CustomProperties in Outlook Object and access same properties while we read mail through Exchange Services?